# Использование разных targetNamespace для одного Wsdl

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

Я использую Spring-ws для написания SOAP-клиента. При этом на сервере используются две wsdl для тестовой и продакшн сред, одинаковые по содержанию, но с разными targetNamespace. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то использовать классы, сгенерированные из одной wsdl, для отправки сообщений в среду с другой wsdl, меняя namespace программным способом?

Answer (score 0):

**На сервере:** В классе-обработчике конечных точек web-сервиса указать:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "myName", targetNamespace = myNamespace)
```

**На клиенте:** В классе, вызывающим конечную точку web-сервиса указать:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "myName", targetNamespace = myNamespace)
```

---

Значение переменной `myNamespace` брать из файла параметров `*.properties`, например так:

```
@Value("${myNamespace}"
String myNamespace;
```

Соответственно для тестовой и продакшн сред параметры разные..

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду? Для клиента нет класса обработчика конечных точек, я нигде использую аннотацию "@WebService(...)", отправка сообщения с помощью webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive 
класса org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate